# LINQ GroupBy return dictionary with given objects as value

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IEnumerable<ValueObj>` object with multiple valid `ValueObj` objects in it. I would like to group those objects by Id and receive `Dictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<ValueObj>>` where the Key is Id from `ValueObj`, and Value is just unchanged `ValueObj`.

```
public class ValueObj
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public double Result { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried to mess with Linq `GroupBy` but with no success

```
IEnumerable<ValueObj> persons = ...;
var results = persons.GroupBy(
    p => p.Id, 
    p => p,
    (key, g) => new { PersonId = key, Cars = g.ToList() });
```

Comment: Where is your query ? What error you get ?

Comment: Have you considered using `ToLookup`?

Comment: So you have multiple instances of `ValueObj` that share the same `Guid`?

Comment: I'd really prefer a lookup `var guidLookup  = persons.ToLookup(p => p.Id);`. Usage is similar to dictionary but you dont get an exception if a guid is not conatained but an empty sequence of objects.

Comment: @HimBromBeere for the sake of simplicity I've created a short example instead of posting my actual heavy object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<ValueObj> col = ...;
var dict = col.GroupBy(x => x.Id).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```